# Overuse of fromIntegral in Haskell

Tags: haskell, integer, double

Whenever I write a function using doubles and integers, I find this problem where I am constantly having to use 'fromIntegral' everywhere in my function. For example:

```
import Data.List

roundDouble
    :: Double
    -> Int 
    -> Double
roundDouble x acc = fromIntegral (round $ x * 10 ** fromIntegral acc) / 10 ** fromIntegral acc
```

Is there an easier way of writing this? (I know there may be easier ways of rounding a number and if there are please let me know! However I am mainly interested in how to avoid using so many 'fromIntegrals'.)

Thanks, Ash

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Sometimes I find a helper function useful:

```
roundDouble x acc = (round $ x * 10 ^ acc) /. (10 ^ acc)
    where 
    x /. y = fromIntegral x / fromIntegral y
```

That helper function can also be written:

```
(/.) = (/) `on` fromIntegral
```

Where `on` is from `Data.Function`.

Comment: And its variant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453608/overuse-of-fromintegral-in-haskell/3458922#3458922

Comment: The type of (/.) is (Integral a, Fractional b, Integral a1) => a -> a1 -> b whereas the type of (/) `on` fromIntegral is (Fractional b, Integral a) => a -> a -> b.

If you need the more general type, on is not appropriate.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `^` instead of `**`. `^` takes any Integral as it's second argument, so you don't need to call `fromIntegral` on the second operand. So your code becomes:

roundDouble x acc = fromIntegral (round $ x * 10 ^ acc) / 10 ^ acc

Which has only one `fromIntegral`. And that one you can't get rid off as `round` naturally returns an Integral and you can't perform non-integer division on an Integral.

Answer (score 6):

I have a similar problem with marshaling code, where `fromIntegral` is used to convert CInt to Int.  I usually define `fI = fromIntegral` to make it easier.  You may also need to give it an explicit type signature or use -XNoMonomorphismRestriction.

If you're doing a lot of math, you may want to look at the [Numeric Prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/numeric-prelude-0.1.3.4), which seems to have much more sensible relations between different numeric types.

Comment: I was expecting to see the answer to be defining fI so I am glad to see someone else write it. I will check out the Numeric Prelude, it looks very useful, thanks!

Comment: Defining fI isn't as slick as some other answers, but it has the broadest applicability compared to the other answers so far.

Answer (score 4):

Another idea, similar to [luqui's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453608/overuse-of-fromintegral-in-haskell/3454211#3454211). Most of my problems with `fromIntegral` are related to necessity to divide `Int` by `Double` or `Double` by `Int`. So this `(/.)` allows to divide any two `Real` types, not necessarily the same, an not necessarily `Integral` types like in luqui's solution:

```
(/.) :: (Real a, Real b, Fractional c) => a -> b -> c
(/.) x y = fromRational $ (toRational x) / (toRational y)
```

Example:

```
ghci> let (a,b,c) = (2::Int, 3::Double, 5::Int)
ghci> (b/.a, c/.a, a/.c)
(1.5,2.5,0.4)
```

It works for any two `Real`s, but I suspect that rational division and conversion to/from `Rational` are not very effective.

Now your example becomes:

```
roundDouble :: Double -> Int -> Double
roundDouble x acc = (round $ x * 10 ^ acc) /. (10 ^ acc)
```